# Python value swapping does nothing

Tags: python, list, swap

I'm currently writing a list sorting function where I'm trying to swap the minimum value of a list with the first element of the list:

```
foo = [4, 7, 2, 9]

foo[0], foo[foo.index(min(foo))] = foo[foo.index(min(foo))], foo[0]
```

I expect the outcome:

```
foo = [2, 7, 4, 9]
```

But instead I get

```
foo = [4, 7, 2, 9]
```

Nothing has changed. Any help?

Comment: The assignment has the effect of assigning `2` to `foo[0]`.  And then assigning `4` to `foo` at the index of the minimum value which is calculated to be `foo[0]` because you just assigned to it.  Even if this worked, it would be very inefficient.  What's wrong with doing `foo.sort()`?

Comment: I'm learning the language and figured a sorting function would be good practice.

Comment: Sorting is a fine way to learn a language.  You may or may not want to peek at my collection of Python/Cython sorts: http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/svn/sorts/compare/trunk/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's break this up with some temporary variables to see what's happening:

```
>>> foo = [4, 7, 2, 9]
>>> tup = foo[foo.index(min(foo))], foo[0]
>>> print tup
(2, 4)
>>> foo[0] = tup[0]
>>> print foo
[2, 7, 2, 9]
>>> dx = foo.index(min(foo))
>>> print dx
0
>>> foo[dx] = tup[1] # foo[dx] equivalent to foo[foo.index(min(foo))]
>>> print foo
[4, 7, 2, 9]
```

The assignment has the effect of assigning `2` to `foo[0]`. And then assigning `4` to `foo` at the index of the minimum value which is calculated to be `foo[0]` because you just assigned to it.

Here's another way to see it by taking note of the order of evaluation:

```
foo[0], foo[foo.index(min(foo))] = foo[foo.index(min(foo))], foo[0]
                                                 1_______
                                       2__________________
                                   3_______________________  4_____
                                   5_______________________________
6_____
                      7_______
            8__________________
        9_______________________
1 find min
2 find index
3 get item by index
4 get item by index
5 make tuple
6 assign to foo at index 0 from left hand side of tuple from step 5)
7 find min
8 find index
9 assign to foo at index from step 8 from right hand side of tuple from step 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
foo = [4, 7, 2, 9]

min_index=foo.index(min(foo))
foo[0], foo[min_index] = foo[min_index], foo[0]
```

Output:

```
[2, 7, 4, 9]
```

Essentially, I think the indexing is getting confused before and after attempted swapping, and as a result, nothing is happening. Whereas, if you know the index before you start trying to swap, the swap works just fine.

Comment: What do you mean by "the indexing is getting confused"?

Answer (score 1):

Steven is correct. Turns out, switching the order of the assignment works just fine.

```
foo = [4, 7, 2, 9]

foo[foo.index(min(foo))], foo[0] = foo[0], foo[foo.index(min(foo))]

foo = [2, 7, 4, 9]
```

It seems as though `foo[foo.index(min(foo))]` on the left hand side of the equation gets redefined after `foo[0]` is reassigned. When the order is swapped, no such redefinition happens.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see what's going on:

```
class ML(list): pass

def log(func):
    def wrapped(*args,**kw):
        rv = func(*args, **kw)
        print rv
        return rv
    return wrapped
foo = ML(foo)
foo.index=log(foo.index)

>>> foo[0], foo[foo.index(min(foo))] = foo[foo.index(min(foo))], foo[0]
2
0
```

So your expression equals to

```
>>> foo[0], foo[0] = foo[2], foo[0]
>>> foo
[4, 7, 2, 9]
```

As you assign value of `foo[2]` to `foo[0]` and revert it back in the same expression, operation becomes idempotent.

Why is it so? Since python evaluates right part of the expression first, it finds that `foo[foo.index(min(foo))], foo[0]` is a tuple `2, 4`. Then it assigns `2` to `foo[0]` from the left hand side, and start to evaluate `foo[foo.index(min(foo))]`. It then founds out that now, as `foo[0] = 2`, that `foo.index(min(foo))` is `0`, and assigns earlier evalueated value `2` to `foo[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

This line:
`foo[0], foo[foo.index(min(foo))] = foo[foo.index(min(foo))], foo[0]`

will first execute `foo[0] = foo[foo.index(min(foo))]` which will mutate the 0th index of the foo list. Then it will execute `foo[foo.index(min(foo))] = foo[0]` but `foo[0]` is already set to the min, so `index()` will find it at the 0th position and assign it. Basically you are trying to do the index arithmetic on the original list, but you aren't taking into account that you are mutating its state in the interim.